# Trying to place a video in bootstrap carousel. But disappears when i set position to fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to place a video in bootstrap carosel. I am trying to move the video around so that it fits the div at a particular responsive hieght not the dimensions of the video itself.

but when i make the video position fixed it just disappears. I'm not sure whats going on here.

**HTML**

```
            <video class="videoInsert" autoplay loop poster="~/Content/video/posters/b-roll-1.jpg" muted>
                <source src="https://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>

        </div>



    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->
```

**CSS**

```
#myCarousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoInsert {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;; 
}
```

and here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/f1fa1ksj/4/

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a little bit more about this: "so that it fits the div at a particular responsive height"... maybe a picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is why the video "disappears": When you make the video `fixed` it get a new stacking context that take it out from the normal flow of where he would normally be. Since every element in the carousel is inside `<div class="item">` and this div doesn't have a height by itself (it grows according to it's content), since the video is now out of the normal flow, the div lose it's height.

Here, i updated your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f1fa1ksj/6/

I added a fixed height to the div:

```
.item {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Also you have to keep in mind there are several `overflow: hidden;` properties in the css of the carousel, like in: `.carousel-inner` and `#myCarousel`. This can affect the visibility of the video depending on the css you apply to it.